# Difference quantity between two arrays values

Tags: php, arrays, difference

I have two arrays who contains product code as key and quantity as value ('code' => quantity). I would like to generate an array who contain difference of quantity between old array (array1) and new array (array2), including any code added or deleted from array1 to array2.

```
$array1 = ['code1' => 1, 'code2' => 2];    
$array2 = ['code1' => 0, 'code2' => 2, 'code3' => 3];

// Array expected
$diffQty = [
    'code1' => -1, // 1 quantity deleted in array 2
    'code2' => 0, // quantity no changed between array1 and array2
    'code3' => 3  // new code added in array2 with 3 quantity
];
```

I tried something like this but I don't have added or deleted code between arrays :

```
$diffQty = [];
foreach ($array2 as $code => $qty) {
    if (array_key_exists($code, $array1)) {
        $diffQty = $array1[$code] - $array2[$code];
        $diffQty[$code] = $diffQty;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to see what have you tried.

Comment: Hi @u_mulder I edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current issue is that you don't do anything in the case where the key doesn't exist in both arrays.

Fetch all the unique keys that exists, and put that into a separate array. Loop the resulting array, which now contains all the keys that exists in both arrays `$array1` and `$array2`. Subtract the values in `$array1` from `$array2`, and if there is no key valid in either array, default it to zero.

```
$array1 = ['code1' => 1, 'code2' => 2];    
$array2 = ['code1' => 0, 'code2' => 2, 'code3' => 3];
$all_keys = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($array1), array_keys($array2)));
$output = array();

foreach ($all_keys as $code) {
    $output[$code] = (!empty($array2[$code]) ? $array2[$code] : 0) - (!empty($array1[$code]) ? $array1[$code] : 0);
}
```

Result of `$output`

```
Array (
    [code1] => -1
    [code2] => 0
    [code3] => 3
)
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/Uic7E)

Comment: It work but if I delete code2 from $array1, it will not added in $output (like 'code2' => -2)

Comment: That wasn't clearly stated in the question, but the revised answer should work with that.

Comment: It was in my question ("including any code added or deleted from array1 to array2"). Your solution work fine, thanks !